# unable to find docker mount point on local laptop

Tags: docker

I have started a `docker` image using command

```
docker run -p 5433:5433 -p 5444:5444 \
           --mount type=volume,source=vertica-data,target=/data \
           --name vertica_ce \
           vertica/vertica-ce
```

I believe `source=vertica-data` is the local mount point for `docker` images's `/data` directory. But I can't fid this directory on my `windows` laptop. Where does `docker` create `vertica-data` directory?

Comment: Usually if you're using Docker named volumes, you shouldn't expect to directly access the files in the volume.  Use a bind-mount instead; `docker run -v $PWD/vertica-data:/data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command creates a named volume. You can list these volumes using `docker volume ls`. `docker volume inspect vertica-data` will show you the path where the data is actually stored.

Apart from named volumes, you may also use bind mounts, which means mounting a directory on the host inside of the container. This can be done using `--mount type=bind,source=/path/on/host,target=/data`

For more information, please refer to the [documentation how to use volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)